# Установить правильный ответ для теста в Google Forms с использованием Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Как правильно задать/установить скриптом правильный ответ для квиза, если использовать вопрос с коротким ответом (`Textitem`)?

Для понимания:

```
function createTestForm() {

// Создаем форму

var form = FormApp.create('Тест');
 form.setIsQuiz(true);


// Вариант с коротким ответом

var textItem = form.addTextItem();

textItem.setTitle('Какой вид спорта самый популярный?');

// Как установить правильный ответ исользуя Google Apps Script? 
// Правильный ответ'Футбол'.

//

var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();

Logger.log('Form created. URL form: ' + formUrl);
```

Визуально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент это невозможно сделать программным способом.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/905644)

Comment: @чистов_n, является. Нормальный ответ.

Comment: Это комментарий. Восемь слов — это никак не ответ. Они, по сути, вообще эквивалентны одному слову: "Нельзя".

Comment: Решили устроить собрание душнил? Я пока не вижу причин вылазить из кожи и приводить обстоятельные объяснения того, почему Гугл скрывает часть реализаций в своем API. Это довольно сложный и запутанный вопрос, который не стоит даже рассматривать тут, в вопросе от явного бота. Поднимите престиж ruSO, потом поговорим.

Comment: Ну, может и ответ. Но по известной "яблочной" классификации это "огрызок"...

Comment: @Глеб, я на опыте. Поверьте, это нормальная порция. Доступная, безопасная и полезная.